# errors building AudioKit Cookbook with v5 beta

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to build [AudioKit Cookbook](https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook) with XCode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300), and I get these errors:

```
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Shaker.swift:13:30: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'start'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Shaker.swift:13:45: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Shaker.swift:40:14: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/DrippingSounds.swift:28:37: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'frequency'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/DrippingSounds.swift:45:19: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'start'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/DrippingSounds.swift:53:15: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/DrumSynthesizers.swift:15:30: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'start'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/DrumSynthesizers.swift:15:45: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/DrumSynthesizers.swift:55:14: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Flute.swift:13:30: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'start'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Flute.swift:13:45: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
/Users/ali/Documents/Development/Cookbook/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Flute.swift:43:14: Value of type 'CallbackLoop' has no member 'stop'
```

Comment: I should add that if I don't compile the 4 swift files listed above and remove the references to them in the views, then Cookbook compiles and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your AudioKit Swift Package to the latest. There were some changes I made in both AudioKit and the Cookbook. I guess I should make master based off v5-master and develop off of v5-develop to prevent this from happening to people in the future.